# Storing .hgignore considered good practice?

Tags: mercurial

I don't often modify this file, but when I do it feels like it isn't good practice. So is storing .hgignore considered good practice?

Comment: The same advice as given in the answers applies to `.gitignore` files with Git, too.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you should keep your .hgignore file in your repo.

https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/QuickStart

> You'll want to track your .hgignore file too!

http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/file-names-and-pattern-matching.html

> To have Mercurial permanently ignore such files, create a file named .hgignore in the root of your repository. You should hg add this file so that it gets tracked with the rest of your repository contents, since your collaborators will probably find it useful too.

Answer (score 2):

I guess that this is kind of subjective, but to me, I'd say it's good practice.

The reason being, the kind of files you want to ignore are the files that change per user, but ultimately don't affect the build.

At my workplace, we ignore our .user files, and we ignore .resharper files (.suo and a few others too).

This is important, as if you add a new project to our solution, we need to ensure the solution builds, but that our user preferences don't muck up anyone else.

Granted, it's rare that we change this or add new projects, but it helps to ensure that everyone has the same build.

So yeah, I think it's fine to keep it, but if you find you're changing it a lot, you might want to examine your reasons for doing so.

Comment: Addendum:  We use SVN a lot, and that has the 'ignore of commit' flag; which is good, as we use that on Web.Config in our .net stuff; the main thing here is that it doesn't stop you checking it in, but it stops it being selected by default on a commit which an be a life saver; I daresay mercurial has a similar function.

Answer (score 0):

With such a lot of IDEs, editors, operating system your `.hgignore` can start to be really big. As such I understand your reluctance to include all of them in your repository. I would tend to say that I don't care about other's IDE/OS and that this make ignore files unreadable.

I chose to maintain my ignored files in two places, one global for editors/IDE/OS garbage and another project specific one for produced files which I store in the repo. The added benefit is that when you start a new project with your favorite IDE, you don't need to ignore anything, it's already done.

For global one, I added the following in my `.hgrc`:

```
[ui]
ignore = ~/.hgignore.global
```

With `.hgignore.global` containing:

```
syntax: glob
# Vim
.*.sw[a-z]
# Eclipse
.project
.settings/
# Unix
*~
# Windows
Thumbs.db
Desktop.ini
# MacOS X
.DS_Store
._*
```

Now you can have minimal project specific `.hgignore`.

- Multiproject Maven example:

  ```
  syntax: glob
  target
  ```
- C project example:

  ```
  syntax: glob
  *.o
  *.so
  bin/mybin
  ```
- Others: you can take inspiration on the wonderful list on [github's gitignore project](https://github.com/github/gitignore), simply add `syntax: glob` on first line.